# CSS backdrop-filter with translate animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a couple elements (which are animated to translate and have differing sizes) and I would like to have attached to each of them a box with the blur backdrop-filter (intended to show up on hover, but I didnt include it here). However, I wasn't getting the effect I wanted, and I found that the blur effect breaks if the parent is animated to transform.

Is there any workaround for this?

```css
.background {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000 url(https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/12A9B/production/_111434467_gettyimages-1143489763.jpg);
}

.blur {
  position: absolute;
  left: -150%;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}

.no-anim {
  position: absolute;
  left: 70%;
  top: 50%;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.animate {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  top: 50%;
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: bob 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes bob {
  from {transform: translateY(0%);}
  to {transform: translateY(20%);}
}
```

```html
<div class="background">

  <div class="no-anim">
    <div class="blur"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="animate">
    <div class="blur"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preserve the blur, I advise you to use the `top` rule instead of `translateY()`.

```
@keyframes bob {
    from {
        top: 50%;
    }
    to {
        top: 55%;
    }
}
```

```css
.background {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #000 url(https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/12A9B/production/_111434467_gettyimages-1143489763.jpg);
}

.blur {
    position: absolute;
    left: -150%;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}

.no-anim {
    position: absolute;
    left: 70%;
    top: 50%;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.animate {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 50%;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation: bob 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    background-color: red;
}

@keyframes bob {
    from {
        top: 50%;
    }
    to {
        top: 55%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
    <div class="no-anim">
        <div class="blur"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="animate">
        <div class="blur"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've implemented this and it works, but the top animation looks notably worse since it moves pixel-by-pixel as opposed to the translate simulating smooth movement. That said, if there's no other way then I'll stick with it. Thanks.

Comment: Also—is there a known reason why the translate animation breaks the blur effect?

Comment: @AaronKirk, And I read some articles about it. Everywhere it is indicated that this is a browser bug.

Comment: Am I allowed to wait and see if there or other responses that might resolve the issue directly?